# Stored Procedures MySql

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask if my stored procedure is correct. I have three tables: employee, attendance_log, and barber_employee. In the stored procedure, when the employee will time in, it will insert a new data in barber employee when that employee is a barber. This procedure was executed well but when I call the stored procedure, even the if the employee is cashier is also added in a barber_employee.

Stored Procedure Query

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE addLogs(IN empID INT, IN ioIN VARCHAR(11))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO attendance_log (emp_id, io) VALUES (empID, ioIN);
IF EXISTS (SELECT e.position, e.status, a.io 
           FROM employee e 
           JOIN  attendance_log a 
           WHERE a.emp_id = `empID`
             AND e.position = 'Barber'
             AND a.io = 'Time In') THEN
  INSERT INTO barber_employee (emp_id, salary, salary_date) VALUES (empID, 0, NOW());
END IF;
END #
DELIMITER ;
```

employee table

[image: employee]

attendance_log table

[image: Attendance_log Table]

barber_employee table

[image: Barber_employee table]

Note: salary_date and log_time are timestamps

Comment: I am not sure but I think EXISTS can be used only in WHERE clauses. Can you try to fetch the SELECT into a local variable and then use that variable in the IF statement ?

Comment: Really I can't even get this procedure to compile - 2 reasons # is not a good choice for delimiter (it denotes a comment in mysql) and secondly the insert 'salary_date' is quoted rather than backticked. Also it's not a viable idea to give parameters the same name as column names and where does e.status come from?

Comment: @P.Salmon I mistakenly quoted the salary_date. I edit the stored procedure query